# Scala Test : Mock deadbolt authentication

Tags: scalatest, deadbolt-2

While running scala test, how can deadbolt auth be mocked so that the requests goes through?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm having similar issues. Deadbolt2 approach feels just wrong anyway, considering it forces your controller to know about the security rules and it's not a cross-cutting concern as it should, but I was not able to find a better library to do authorization...